# Setting data dynamically with SmartGwt SelectItem

Tags: smartgwt

In my web application, I need to fetch data from server to populate contents in a SelectItem. And I use SelectItem.setValueMap(LinkedHashMap), but there is always a random number added at the end of the contents. Below is my codes:

```
In constructor:
SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem("category");
selectItem .setRequired(true);
selectItem .setTitle("Category");
selectItem .setMultiple(true);
selectItem .setMultipleAppearance(MultipleAppearance.GRID);
selectItem .setHeight(60);

Some where other thant constructor:
LinkedHashMap<String , String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
// fetch data from server and pop up the map...
selectItem .setValueMap(map);
```

Could someone help me with that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not really clear, neither what you are doing nor what you are getting wrong. Try to give us more details

Comment: I use SelectItem.setValueMap(LinkedHashMap) to set the contens in SelectItem, but there is always one random number will be added to the end of the contents of SelectItem. The contents is set at run time, so not inside the constructor. I tried SelectItem.setValueMap(String ...) and this works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're testing in Chrome development mode - can't do this, because there's a GWT/Chrome bug that will add extra data to every object, like you're seeing.

Explained further, with references to the GWT and Chrome bugs for this, here:

http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159#aChrome